# How the detect the "edittext" box whether it is nothing in Android?

Tags: android

I want to program a function that the toast exist when there is nothing 
in the "edittext" box (id / password), but it dosen't work.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.EditText; 
import android.widget.Toast; 
import android.view.View.OnClickListener; 
import android.text.Editable; 

public class Test extends Activity
{

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    EditText id = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.id);
    EditText pwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pwd);
    Editable Str_id;
    Editable Str_pwd;
    Str_id = id.getText();
    Str_pwd = pwd.getText();



    button1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
    {

      public void onClick(View v){
        if(Str_id==null || Str_pwd == null){
        Toast.makeText(Test.this, "Please Enter User ID / Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     }
    });
    }



  }
```

Answer (score 0):

move the following lines inside onClick and try:

```
Str_id = id.getText(); 
Str_pwd = pwd.getText();
```

EDIT: Move

```
Editable Str_id; 
Editable Str_pwd; 
Str_id = id.getText(); 
Str_pwd = pwd.getText();
```

inside onClick().

Comment: When the onCreate() is executing the views are not even drawn so, getText() in onCreate wouldnt work or should at least yield unexepected behavior.

Comment: Error, it recommend to "change modifier of "id" and "pwd" to final.

Comment: depending on your need you can do any of the following:
1. move the declarations of those fields inside onClick() or
2. Make those fields as instance variables of the class by moving them outside onCreate.

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend toasting a message that a field is required. You're better off just giving the EditText focus, this focus tells the user that this field is required. Its less information on the screen and its subtle, which is important. You don't want to disturb the user too much.

The idea is...

When the submit button is clicked, check the EditTexts if any of them are empty, notify the user through requesting focus, also make sure your UI tells them before hand that the fields required. The hint of the EditText works well for this.